# Complex mysql query with conditional results

Tags: mysql

I have the next structure in a MySQL database:

```
boats
id    name
-------------
1     name1
2     name2

boat_prices
id boat_id       date       duration      price     is_default  
---------------------------------------------------------------
1     1       '2018-01-01'       1         100          
2     1       '2018-01-01'       2         200          
3     1          null          null        100           1
4     2       '2018-01-02'       2         400
5     2       '2018-01-02'       4         800
6     2          null          null        200           1
7     3       '2018-01-03'       5        1500
8     3          null          null        300           1
```

The boats have a price for a specific date and duration in days.
All boats have a default "from" price that is identified by date = null and duration = null. 
But, not all boats have prices for all days. 
When I search for boat prices for a specific date and duration, the query should return all rows with a price for that date and duration, and in case a boat hasn´t got a price for that date return its "from" default price.

Example: For the date = '2018-01-01 and duration = 1, the result should be:

```
boat_prices
id boat_id       date       duration      price       is_default
----------------------------------------------------------------
1     1       '2018-01-01'       1         100       
6     2          null          null        200           1
8     3          null          null        300           1
```

I did this query example just to simplify, but please take into account apart from this, the query has some other joins with other tables.

I need help with the query.

Comment: Sample table structure with data ?

Comment: It's not a good idea to mix implicit and explicit joins - in my view you shouldn't use implicit joins at all.

Comment: Please see the update for more details. In that case, any suggestion. What should be the approach?

Comment: Sample included @MadhurBhaiya

Comment: No attempt has been made to show a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) : Please delete as much of your query as possible, leaving the absolute minimum amount of sql that demonstrates the problem. Right now, 90% of it is irrelevant and of no use to future visitors.

Comment: Query edited @Bohemian .

Comment: Why in your result the boat_id are 1 and 2 ? Shouldn't it be 1 and 1 ? with price 100 ?

Comment: No. The result should return all the boats. For those which has a price for a specific date it should return that price, and for those which don´t have a price it should return the "from" default price. The example is ok.

Comment: Tahnks for precisions

Comment: What is Use of boat table here? not clear by given detail. Please explain more precisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Rick was on the right direction having left join, but you probably need TWO.  One to get the boat prices that qualify the date interested in, another explicitly for the default.

```
select 
      b.id,
      b.name,
      DefPrice.price as DefaultPrice,
      Specials.price as SpecialsPrice,
      COALESCE( Specials.price, DefPrice.price ) as DiscountOrDefaultPrice
   from
      ( select @parmDate = '2018-01-01' ) sqlvars,
      boats b
         JOIN boat_prices DefPrice
            on b.id = DefPrice.boat_id
           AND DefPrice.date IS NULL
           AND DefPrice.Duration IS NULL
         LEFT JOIN boat_prices Specials
            on b.id = Specials.boat_id
           AND Specials.date <= @parmDate
           AND @parmDate <= Date_Add( Specials.Date, INTERVAL (Specials.duration -1 ) DAY )
```

Now, you could always return only the one price in question by doing a COALESCE() in case there is no Specials price, it gets the default via the DiscountOrDefaultPrice column.

Take your pick version of which column(s) you want to run with.  This should get ALL boats, regardless of some special price based on durations.  As you change whatever your parameter date in question is -- even if you do a current date, it will work.  This is because you are testing the date in question against ALL possible special boat prices and its beginning to beginning + duration end date range.  If you have multiple prices that overlap dates, that will just return those multiple rows that overlap.

My Adding of the duration is subtracting 1.  For example, if your date is 2018-01-01 and its good for 1 day, does that mean it is only good for that one day? or up to and including 2018-01-02.  The -1 forces the qualification to just the one day.  So the price on 2018-01-01 good for 1 day is ONLY 2018-01-01.

Your other example for 2018-01-02 has two day duration.  To me, indicating 2 days including 01-02 through 01-03.  Two actual days.

CONFIRMATION from comment about dates and range

I guess my interpretation was wrong then on your data needs.  Your sample of TWO dated boat price records apparently is not enough.  You stated you want ALL boats regardless of qualification of a special price record. So you must start with the boat and the join to get all possible "Default" pricing no matter what.  It is only the LEFT-JOIN component that needs to be adjusted.

That being said, lets simulate more data. Assume you have the following

```
Boad ID    Date        Duration    Rate
1        2018-01-01       1        x
1        2018-01-02       4        y
2        2018-01-02       2        z
2        2018-01-04       4        a
3        2018-01-03       5        b
```

If I provide the date 2018-01-01, what rate records should I see?
If I provide date 2018-01-03, what records?
If I provide date 2018-01-05, what records?

Comment: Hey guys: I understand your approach but if I´m not wrong the query has still some mistake, I integrated your approach in the query and specials.price is always null. It gets only the def values.

Comment: One more point, is not really important for the solution but you don´t need to calculate the interval. There is a price for each date and all different possible durations, so you can just cross by date = ? AND duration = ?

Comment: @Rober, see my revised comments at the bottom for clarification.

Comment: For clarification I have updated my question with your sample data. Please read the use cases below the sample data table. I hope it´s clear. I don´t know if your query should be changed now, but I have updated my query with your new changes and I get the same result. The specials column is always null.

Comment: Your query is right! Sorry, the reason why I got null results for specials is that I just typed '2018-01-01' instead of '2018-10-01'. But don´t worry, I have just lash 20 times myself.

Answer (score 1):

For the particular date "2018-01-01" and duration of 1, i will use an UNION clause like this:

(Note: Edited for add **is_default** column)

```
-- Get prices for particular day and duration.
(SELECT
    boat_id,
    date,
    duration,
    price,
    0 AS is_default
FROM
    boat_prices
WHERE
    date = "2018-01-01" AND duration = 1)

UNION

-- Add defaults prices for those don't have a price on the particular day and duration
(SELECT
    boat_id,
    date,
    duration,
    price,
    is_default
FROM
    boat_prices
WHERE
    date IS NULL
AND 
    duration IS NULL
AND
    boat_id NOT IN (SELECT boat_id
                    FROM boat_prices
                    WHERE date ="2018-01-01" AND duration = 1))
```

**EXAMPLE WITH STORED PROCEDURE SOLUTION**

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE GetPricesByDateAndDuration(IN pDate DATE, IN pDuration INT)
BEGIN

    -- Get prices for particular day and duration.

    (SELECT
        boat_id,
        date,
        duration,
        price,
        0 AS is_default
    FROM
        boat_prices
    WHERE
        date = pDate AND duration = pDuration)

    UNION

    -- Add defaults prices for those don't have a price on the particular day and duration

    (SELECT
        boat_id,
        date,
        duration,
        price,
        is_default
    FROM
        boat_prices
    WHERE
        date IS NULL
    AND 
        duration IS NULL
    AND
        boat_id NOT IN (SELECT boat_id
                        FROM boat_prices
                        WHERE date = pDate AND duration = pDuration))

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Then you can call the procedure like this:

```
CALL GetPricesByDateAndDuration('2018-01-01', 1);
```

Comment: I think you are missing  the point.  The 2018-01-01 is just a SAMPLE Date.  What if the date is 3 months down the road.  They don't need a solution for a single day, but need based on its own date / duration merits.  What about boat #2 or #3 that start on 2017-12-29 and good for 10 days... That too would qualify for the results of special pricing.

Comment: In the case date and duration are parameters, the query can be putted inside a stored procedure that receive both: date and duration parameters. I will update mi answer to show this.

Comment: Although your answer is completely right too, I sorry that I gave the 50 point to @Drapp . I wish I could split the points. The only reason is that I have a complex query with a lot of joins and conditions, and to use the UNION means to duplicate a lot and probably to have a worse performance in the query, due to the query is somehow executed twice. But your answer is right! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that clunky output, consider:

```
boat_id      price   default     
-----------------------------
   1          100
   2          300   (default)
```

Something like this should generate that:

```
SELECT  boat_id,
        IF(b.price IS NULL, dflt.price, b.price) AS price,
        IF(b.price IS NULL, '(default)', '')  AS default
    FROM       boat_prices AS dflt
    LEFT JOIN  boat_prices AS b  USING(boat_id)
    WHERE  dflt.date IS NULL
      AND  dflt.duration IS NULL
      AND  '2018-01-01' >= b.date
      AND  '2018-01-01' <  b.date + INTERVAL b.duration DAY
    GROUP BY  boat_id
```

Comment: I think you are missing the point. The 2018-01-01 is just a SAMPLE Date. What if the date is 3 months down the road. They don't need a solution for a single day, but need based on its own date / duration merits. What about boat #2 or #3 that start on 2017-12-29 and good for 10 days... That too would qualify for the results of special pricing.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it clear that `date` can be a range, not a single constant.

Comment: I agree, it is somewhat unclear, but if I wanted to know what prices were on a given date, I should just have to ask for said date.  They are probably out for the night as gone for 6+ hours, get answers in the morning I guess :)

Comment: @DRapp - I tweaked my answer to deal with `duration`.

Comment: I think you are missing to join with the boats table to get only the boats that meets the other conditions.

Comment: @Rober - Your sample output did not use the `boats` table, so I did not.  My solution can be modified to turn `boat_id` into `boats.name`.